# Printing Results in a Simple Table

Tags: php, sql, mysql

I have a MySQL table with a structure similar to this:

```
id1 id2 title url date
```

I would like to print out a simple table in PHP that with the following structure sorted in reverse chronological order for the most recent 10 entries (date above = date submitted) from the MySQL table:

```
title id2
```

How could I do this?

Answer (score 1):

Use:

```
<table>
  <tr>
    <td>title</td>
    <td>id2</td>
  </tr>
<?php
  $sql = "SELECT t.title, 
                 t.id2
            FROM TABLE t
        ORDER BY t.date DESC
           LIMIT 10";

  $result = mysql_query($sql) or die(mysql_error()); 

  while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result, MYSQL_NUM)) {
    printf("<tr><td>%s</td><td>%s</td></tr>", $row[0], $row[1]);
  }
?>
</table>
```

`ORDER BY t.date DESC` will list the most recent date at the top.  If you want the list to start with the earliest date, omit the `DESC` - the default is `ASC`, so you don't have to type it out.